# Is it possible to provide standard deviation to create dose response curve fits?

Tags: r, math, curve-fitting, drc

I am using the `drc` R package to fit four-parameter dose response curves to my data. I usually have replicates of four that I supply for one concentration. Would it be possible to provide the mean and standard deviation of these values instead? My math skills are limited and maybe I am missing an obvious solution.

The function I am using has the following form:

```
drc::drm(
      response ~ dose,
      data = data,
      fct = drc::LL.4()
    )
```

There are some normalisation procedures I would like to apply to my data that will yield a mean with standard deviations instead of four replicate values. If there is no way of directly supplying this to this function, would it be possible to create two points that lie on the outer edges of my standard deviation and then use these points for the function?

Lets assume:

```
mean = 5
sd = 2.5
point1 = 2.5
point2 = 7.5
```

Would be great if someone that understands more about those things could help! Thanks a lot!